# What should a beginner look for in a sextant?

Tags: sailing

I have an interest in sextants and how they work, mostly from reading the Horatio Hornblower novels.

I know that sextants are still sold, and while I am sure that are not nearly as precise as GPS is nowadays it would still be a fun project to learn how to use them.

What should a beginner look for when purchasing their first sextant?

Comment: Look for one that has a good GPS antenna.

Comment: coteyr's answer has exposed an ambiguity which I was not even aware of: apparently a navigator's sextant and an astronomer's sextant are different devices. I am assuming you mean a **navigator's sextant**, the one with the mirrors that is more complicated than merely reading off a protractor.

Comment: It appears that an astronomer's sextant is little more than a partial quadrant: essentially a protractor for measuring angles in the sky that only goes up to 60 degrees rather than the quadrant's usual 90.

Comment: Navigator's sextant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low cost, or flash. Or make your own, they are "easy" to make.

When learning how to use one (there is a reason they are still sold) it doesn't have to be precise. You just need something to practice with. https://www.popsci.com/make-sextant-from-junk

They are very easy to use and very easy to make. If you are just looking to learn, these really simple ones should get you started.

Comment: While not strictly an integral part of the question, it would still make this good answer even better if you could give a short description of a self-made sextant in the answer itself. Looking at the link it's super simple, so it should be doable in very few sentences.

Comment: My first reaction to this was "Aren't you talking about a quadrant?" However, on further approach, it appears that a navigation sextant and an astronomical sextant are not quite the same device.